# Jquery Tricky object detection

Tags: jquery, object, properties, attributes

I am calling a variable o from a function getStuff(o) ;

- o can be a value --> 12456 or
- o is an object of type HTMLTableRowElement (in that case a tr with id="*whatever number 123...*")

I need a jquery script to capture o value or o tr attr(id) value.

I tried something like:

```
function getStuff(o) {
    if ($(this).find("tr").hasAttr("lex-id")) {
        // o is HTMLTableRowElement 
        var id = this.attr("lex-id") ;
    } else {
        // o is a number
        var id = o ;
    }
```

but it returns an error *"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).hasAttr is not a function"*

Your help is the most welcome.
Thanks in advance
Jacques

Comment: jQuery has no `hasAttr()` method: https://api.jquery.com. Also, depending on how you call `getStuff()`, the `this` reference is unlikely to be a Element. I'd suggest using `typeof` to determine what `o` contains and then branch your logic from there

Comment: Thank you Rory. You are right and i manage with your suggestion. ;)